# Contour Integration with $\sec{(\sqrt{1-x^2})}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I've found that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sec{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}\,dx = \pi^2\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (2k+1)}{\sqrt{\pi^2(2k+1)^2-4}} \approx 4.89477$$

by way of just playing around with some contours, in particular, a semicircle avoiding the branch (to which I defined to just be $[-1,1]$), then summing the infinite residues along the imaginary axis.

Is there any way to exploit a branch (dog-bone?) in a similiar to compute a series representation of

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \sec{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}\,dx \, ?$$

Perhaps one way to make some progress is via a trig substitution?

Comment: Do you wanna calculate the integral?

Comment: Because $\sec$ is an even function, there are no branch points in a complex integral having that integrand, so a "dog-bone" contour would not be helpful.

Comment: @RonGordon Hmm, you’re right..that’s what I get for doing math so late! Oddly enough plotting real and imaginary parts in Mathematic showed the branch cuts, so I just went with it. I guess this means I just deformed my original contour when it could’ve been a semicircle the entire time. Silly me!